# jquery function call from html without passing this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**The way I know:**

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="msg" onclick="foo(this);" />
```

JS:

```
function foo(elementObj) { elementObj.toggle(); }
```

Is there any way to get reference to `elementObj` inside `foo()` without passing it as function argument?

**How I want to do:**

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="msg" onclick="foo();" />
```

JS:

```
function foo() { elementObj = <any way I can get ref to html element here?>; elementObj.toggle(); }
```

P.S.

Call function like this: `$("#msg").click(function(elementObj ) {elementObj.toggle();}`

Is not what I need.

Comment: What's wrong with the example you just provided?  Just because you pass _this_ as an argument, it doesn't mean you have to actually use the parameter.

Comment: you can use `event` instead of `this`, but I suppose it's the same for you.

Comment: "Call function like this [...] Is not what I need" what do you need then? The only problem I see with your code is that you're calling .toggle on a jQuery event object. Otherwise, there is absolutely no reason to be using `onclick` at all.

Comment: Did you downvote my answer without even testing it? Fair enough, -1 and a CV for the terrible question.

Comment: @jahroy I fear that a DOM element does not have a `.toggle()` method. `;]` The question is not constructive at all and can't be properly answered.

Comment: Agreed that the question is poorly composed... I was just trying to show how you can reference a _different_ element in a javascript function.  It would be trivial to create a jQuery object from the DOM element by wrapping it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to get reference to `elementObj` inside `foo()` without passing it as function argument?

Yes, just use proper unobtrusive jQuery event handler attaching such as [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), or its shorthands:

```
$('#msg').click(function() {
    //`this` references the clicked DOM element #msg
});
```

Or if you need to use the function `foo` elsewhere..

```
function foo(eventObject) { 
    //`this` reference the #msg element
}
$('#msg').click(foo);
```

---

As per OP edit:

```
function foo() {
   elementObj = <any way I can get ref to html element here?>;
   elementObj.toggle();
}
```

Yeah just use the ID selector `$('#msg')` or `$(this)` if you want to reference the clicked element.

```
function foo() {
   var elementObj = $(this);
   elementObj.toggle();
   //or more directly $(this).toggle()
}
$('#msg').click(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks fine to me.

Just because you pass a parameter in a function, it doesn't mean you have to use it.

You can get a reference to **any element you want** inside your function:

```
<input type="button" onclick="foo(this);" />

<script>

    function foo(thisIsNotUsed) {
        var anotherElement = document.getElementById("someId");
        // create a jQuery object before invoking toggle
        jQuery(anotherElement).toggle();
    }

</script>
```

NOTE:

I'm pretty sure it's consensus opinion that registering a handler with HTML is a horrible practice.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the reference by using jquery, try the following:

```
<input type="button" onclick="foo(this);" />

//javascript
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input').on('click', function(){
      var theElement = $(this);
   });
});
```